# How did WCAG come up with the constants used in determining luminance

Tags: color

In https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G17.html they used a few constants but I can't find where they're derived from

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you follow some of the links further you will get to the page about the information on the [Standard Default Color Space for the Internet](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/Color/sRGB.html) - sRGB. There are a number of definitions described in more detail (example in screenshot).

[image]

However, I am curious as to why you are interested in finding out the constants because the calculations are done by tools which are standard in the industry. Wherever possible, it is certainly easier to use standard tools rather than trying to do the calculations yourself.

Comment: so where'd they get 0.3127 and 0.3291 I did follow but it seems to show more constants.

Comment: Those seem to be defined values for the CIE color space system. So the value of 0.3127 (x value, CIE D65) comes from the TABLE 0.2 CIE chromaticities for ITU-R BT.709 reference primaries and CIE standard illuminant, while 0.3291 (y value, CIE D65) might have been rounded up in the article since I couldn't find an exact match.

Comment: but then again how do they get the constants that are used in the luminace equation.  The table which you had posted do not have any values that match the numbers in the equation.

Comment: Those questions might be beyond the scope of UXSE, and probably something for a science related forum :p